# How to add 'Arial.ttf ' font file in flutter project

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

I am use the (syncfusion_flutter_pdf) plug to generation pdf file when you need draw text using TrueType fonts and run this code give me this error (***Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'Arial.ttf' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2***))

**How Can Add 'Arial.ttf' Font File In Project Files and Open from Class File ?**

```
//Create a new PDF document

PdfDocument document = PdfDocument();

//Draw text
document.pages.add().graphics.drawString('Hello World!!!',
    PdfTrueTypeFont(File('Arial.ttf').readAsBytesSync(), 14),
    brush: PdfBrushes.black, bounds: Rect.fromLTWH(10, 10, 300, 50));

//Saves the document
File('Output.pdf').writeAsBytes(document.save());

//Disposes the document
document.dispose()
```

;

Answer (score 1):

The font 'Arial.ttf' must be available on App folder, for example `data/user/0/com.example.app/app_flutter/`.

Use  getApplicationDocumentsDirectory from path_provider to get the directory path.

```
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

Future<File> getFileFromAssets(String filename) async {
  assert(filename != null);

  String directory = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
  final asset= '$directory/$filename';

  final File file = File(asset);
  return file;
}

File font = await getFileFromAssets('fonts/Arial.ttf');

font: PdfTrueTypeFont(font.readAsBytesSync(), 80),
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to download the arial text.
Make a folder in the app. Paste your downloaded files in that folder.
Use the Below code in the Pubspec.yaml . But use your own folder and files name in pubspec ok.
its jst dummynames and spelling

```
fonts:
     - family: Arial
       fonts:
         - asset: fonts/arial-Regular.ttf
```